# Is there a way to sort countries in Rails based on a particular order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to order an array in Rails by countries but I would like certain countries to feature higher than others e.g. United Kingdom at 1, United States at 2, Germany at 3, etc.

The extra bit of complication is that I first need to order by year. So for example if a record was created in 1969 in UK I want that to be first followed by a record in 1969 in Germany.

I tried the following but I do not think I am even close:

My View:

```
<% @versions.sort_by do |version | version.country_order %>
   <%= render 'version_card', version: version %>
 <% end %>
```

In the Version model I added this method:

```
def country_order
    return 0 if master.country_code == country_code
    return 1 if country_code == "UK"
    return 2 if country_code == "US"
    return 3 if country_code == "DE"
    return 4 if country_code == "FR"
    return 5 if country_code == "JP"
 end
```

And finally in the Master controller (as the Master shows all of the Versions available):

```
def show
 @versions = Kaminari.paginate_array(versions_search).page(params[:page]).per(VERSIONS_PER_ROW)
 @versions.sort_by! { |version | version.release_year }
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you show an example of your unsorted and sorted data?

Comment: `@versions.sort_by! { |version| [version.release_year, version.country_order] }` should work. And in your view simply `@versions.each do |version|` since the controller already sorted the array.

Comment: BTW `[master.country_code, 'UK', 'US', 'DE', 'FR', 'JP'].index(country_code)` is a more concise way to express the country order.

Comment: You might want to look into [rendering a collection of partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections). `<%= render partial: 'version_card', collection: @versions, as: :version %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on [Stefan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075117/is-there-a-way-to-sort-countries-in-rails-based-on-a-particular-order#comment104388255_59075117), we can first sort by the release year, then a special country order, then by the country itself.

```
class Version
  SPECIAL_COUNTRY_ORDER = ["UK", "US", "DE", "FR", "JP"]

  attr_accessor :country_code, :release_year

  def initialize(country_code:, release_year:)
    @country_code = country_code
    @release_year = release_year
  end

  def special_country_order
    SPECIAL_COUNTRY_ORDER.index(country_code) || SPECIAL_COUNTRY_ORDER.size
  end

  def to_s
    "#{country_code} #{release_year}"
  end
end

versions = [
  Version.new(country_code: "DE", release_year: 1969),
  Version.new(country_code: "UK", release_year: 1969),
  Version.new(country_code: "JP", release_year: 1999),
  Version.new(country_code: "AA", release_year: 1999),
  Version.new(country_code: "BB", release_year: 1999),
  Version.new(country_code: "ZZ", release_year: 1999),
  Version.new(country_code: "BB", release_year: 2000)
]

puts versions.sort_by { |version|
  [version.release_year, version.special_country_order, version.country_code]
}
```

If a country doesn't have a special country order it gets a number greater than any of the special countries. Since it's greater it sorts below them. Since it's the same number the sort moves on to the next sort key: the country code itself.

Here's what it's sorting by.

```
[1969, 2, "DE"]
[1969, 0, "UK"]
[1999, 4, "JP"]
[1999, 5, "AA"]
[1999, 5, "BB"]
[1999, 5, "ZZ"]
[2000, 5, "BB"]
```

And the result.

```
UK 1969
DE 1969
JP 1999
AA 1999
BB 1999
ZZ 1999
BB 2000
```